# Is water based exterior paint meaningfully more breathable than pliolite?

Tags: paint, exterior

I'm looking to repaint a rendered exterior (normal render not lime). Viable paints include

- pliolite e.g. Leyland Pliolite
- acrylic e.g. Dulux Weathershield

All paint manufacturers claim their paints are breathable to some extent, but I get the impression acrylic paints are more breathable than pliolite.  That said, are they *meaningfully* more breathable in this context? (I've never seen any actual numbers comparing the two).

Allowing the wall to dry when it's dry outside is obviously preferable, but if prevailing weather conditions mean painting in pliolite now or waiting until Spring for acrylic, is it worth waiting?

Comment: Where are you at?

Comment: Wales, United Kingdom